# iTextSharp Table Page Spanning Horizontally

Tags: itext

I have a table in iTextSharp, but it is fairly wide. I need it to be able to span across pages like this:

Page1 Page2

Page3 Page4

I cannot seem to find documentation saying if this is even possible or not. How would I do this? Ideally, I could say that Page1 and Page3 has Columns1-3, and Page2 and Page4 would have Columns4-6.

Is is possible, and how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the method `WriteSelectedRows` as described in chapter 4 of "iText in Action".

- A Java example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=90
- The corresponding C# example: http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter04&ex=Zhang

Note that this will require you to measure the height of the rows, because you'll have to select specific rows, and you'll have to position the different parts of the table at absolute positions.

Comment: Yeah, this worked great, that example really sped us along, thanks!